# Fastly 400 error "exceeding_max_backends" when creating Fastly Service through pulumi

Tags: pulumi, fastly

I sometimes get a 400 error when creating my Fastly Service through pulumi. The error message is below.

```
error: 1 error occurred:
    * updating urn:my:cdn: 400 - Bad Request:

    Title:  Bad request
    Detail: Exceeding max_backends: 5
```

I've had more than 5 backends in other Fastly services, and if I retry the deployment the 400 error goes away. Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I have to raise the limits on our fastly account https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/resource-limits